# Is Bouncy Castle the default security provider for JBoss 6.4?

Tags: java, jboss, bouncycastle, jboss6.x, java-security

Normally, the following file includes the default security provider for Java

```
java-home/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

by setting `security.provider.n=provider-class-name`

Does JBoss 6.4 override this and make Bouncy Castle its default security implementation?